# Populate Tabs on a DocuSign Envelope Definition Using NodeJs SDK

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign [NodeJS SDK](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-Node-Client) to create a signing request from a template that I've already set up from the DocuSign console. I've also set up a text field on the document. I want to automatically populate this field when I send the signing request.

Here is the relevant part of my code (most of it is just copied from the recipes):

```
var envDef = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.setEmailSubject('Ready for Signing');
envDef.setTemplateId(templateId); 

  // create a template role with a valid templateId and roleName and assign signer info
var tRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();
tRole.setRoleName("Role1");
tRole.setName(role1FullName);
tRole.setEmail(role1Email);
tRole.setClientUserId(role1UserId);

/**************SET TABS******************/
//set tabs
var text = new docusign.Text();
text.setTabLabel("textFoo"); //This is the data label I setup from the console.
text.setValue("Foo Bar Zoo"); //Some text I want to have pre-populated

var textTabs = [];
textTabs.push(text);

var tabs = new docusign.Tabs();
tabs.setTextTabs(textTabs);

tRole.setTabs(tabs);
/**************END SET TAB******************/

// create a list of template roles and add our newly created role
var templateRolesList = [];
templateRolesList.push(tRole);

// assign template role(s) to the envelope
envDef.setTemplateRoles(templateRolesList);



// send the envelope by setting |status| to 'sent'. To save as a draft set to 'created'
envDef.setStatus('sent');
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Bad Request
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\janak\NodeProjects\DocuFire\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:823:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\janak\NodeProjects\DocuFire\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1046:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Note:** If I comment out the `SET TABS` part this code runs fine and I can retrieve the signing url and redirect my user there.

What am I doing wrong?

This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600349/how-to-pre-fill-tabs-on-a-server-template-with-the-docusign-api) seems to answer this question when requesting with some form of XML API. But how can I do this using the NodeJs SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my code is correct, but there is a bug in the SDK: [Unable to send tabs #50](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/issues/50).

**Solution:**

> I was correctly constructing the request -- but the node client populates all empty model parameters with null
>
> Recursively stripping the nulls from the envelope before submitting the request solved this issue for me:
>
> ```
> removeNulls = function(envelope) {
>   var isArray = envelope instanceof Array;
>     for (var k in envelope) {
>       if (envelope[k] === null) isArray ? obj.splice(k, 1) : delete envelope[k];
>       else if (typeof envelope[k] == "object") removeNulls(envelope[k]);
>       if (isArray && envelope.length == k) removeNulls(envelope);
>     }
>   return envelope;
> }
> ```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871943/docusign-request-returns-error-only-when-tabs-set)

I used this function like so:

```
tRole.setTabs(removeNulls(tabs));
```